# Lilypond Markup Alignment

Tags: lilypond, engraving, computer

I have a fairly large note on how to program the keyboard in my piece that I would like to put between the right-hand staff and the left-hand staff. When I `R1*3/4^\markup{\left-column{"G126 Vibra...`, I get

[image: Not right]

It looks like the text is centered over the whole-bar rest. When I change to `r1*3/4^\markup{\left-column{"G126 Vibra...`, then I get

[image: Nearly correct]

which is close, but you can see that the whole rest is not aligned properly.

Any tips on how to left-align text above objects, or perhaps how to attach text to the beginning of staves would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to attach the markup to a hidden voice with an `s` spacer.  Tell the voice with the bar rest to act like it is the only voice with the `\oneVoice` command, so that it doesn't get misplaced.

Also, use the `\whiteout` command to stop the bar lines from interfering with the text.

```
\score{
    {
        \new PianoStaff {
            \set PianoStaff.instrumentName = "Keyboard"
            <<
                \new Staff {
                    \clef "treble"
                    \time 3/4
                    \key aes \major
                        R2.*6 |
                }
                \new Staff {
                    \clef "bass"
                    \time 3/4
                    \key aes \major
                        << { \oneVoice R2. }
                        \\ { s2. 
                                ^\markup { 
                                    \whiteout \pad-markup #0.5
                                    \left-column {
                                        "G126 Vibraphone;lfo1 frequency 68"
                                        "amp1 mod lfo1 ams sw1 mod, intensity +25"
                                    } 
                                } 
                            } 
                        >> |
                        R2.*5 |
                }
            >>
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Image of code rendering with markup attached to spacer]

Comment: That's as good of an hack as I could have hoped for :-D Given how much has gone into markup, I'm really surprised there aren't alignment options like this :shrug:. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, and seeing your answer makes me sorry I didn't provide a minimum working example. Thanks for your trouble!